# VirtualBox WSL2 file sharing from Debian

Tags: debian, windows, virtualbox, file-sharing

I have Windows 10 as a primary OS and there is installed VirtualBox with Debian Buster.

I use WSL2 and I would like to see files from this virtual PC in folder `\\wsl$`. It works automatically when I use Debian from Windows Store. Is it even possible to use it like this for VirtualBox?

Thank you.